# How to fill multiple textboxes based on selected row in listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have written a method that populates multiple rows in a listbox (but only displays the Registration number). These rows are called `registrationNumber`, `hireCost`, `carMake`, `carModel`, and `carYear`. As it only displays the registration number, I want to populate some textboxes when I select the registration number in the listbox.

I have made a general method of how I believe it will function, but am not sure how to implement it.

**Code for inserting data**

```
public void UpdateListBox(string registrationNumber, string hireCost, string carMake, string carModel, string carYear) { 
foreach (string item in listBoxVehicles.Items)
    {
        if (item.Contains(registrationNumber))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Registration Number: " + registrationNumber + " already exists in the list! Please try another!");
            return;
        }
    }
    listBoxVehicles.Items.Add(registrationNumber);
}
```

**Code for selecting row**

```
private void PopulateTextBoxes() {
    if (listBoxVehicles.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        textBoxHireCost.Text = "Selected index hireCost";
        textBoxMake.Text = "Selected index carMake";
        textBoxModel.Text = "Selected index carModel";
        textBoxYear.Text = "Selected index carYear";
    } 
}
```

Here is how it might look when I click on a registration number
as the attached image below. The fields on the right have been populated.

[image: Example]

How might I populate the values of the selected registration number into the textboxes?

**Edit**
Here is the method that gets the data for the listbox from another form:

```
private void StoreData()
{
    //Store Data
    HomeForm list = (HomeForm)Application.OpenForms["HomeForm"];
    list.UpdateListBox(textBoxRegistrationNumber.Text, textBoxHireCost.Text + "     ", textBoxMake.Text + "     ", textBoxModel.Text + "     ", textBoxYear.Text);
    this.Hide();
}
```

Comment: Where did your original ROWs come from that are put into the Listbox?  Is it a datatable?  You need to bind the textboxes to columns in a table so when a row is selected in the table the texboxes automatically get populated.  See : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6f97a00a-78ab-4e10-bcdf-c2e5a3bd4c1c/how-to-bind-a-textbox-with-datatables-column?forum=wpf

Comment: They are inputted from another form. I will add the code to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modern programming, there is a tendency to separate your data (= model) from the way that the data is displayed (= view). If you separate them, you will be able to change the way you display the data without having to change your model.

Similarly you can change the model, without having to change the view. For instance, your current model fetches the data from a database, but you won't have to change anything on your view if you decide to read the data from a JSON-file.

Separation of model and view also enables unit testing your model without forms.

Separation of model and view needs something to glue them together. This "adapter" is often called the viewmodel. The abbreviation of these items is often called MVVM.

So let's separate!

Apparently your model has the notion of cars that can be hired. So we need a class:

```
class Car
{
    public string RegistrationNumber {get; set;}
    public decimal HireCost {get; set;}
    public int ManufacturingYear {get; set;}
    ... // etc.
}
```

And of course we need a procedure to fetch the cars that must be displayed:

```
public IEnumerable<Car> FetchCars(...)
{
    // TODO implement; out of scope of the question
}
```

Using the visual designer you have added the ListBox. This ListBox should display Cars, and for every Car it should display only the registration number.

You can do this using the visual studio designer, another method would be to do it in the constructor:

```
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // From ever Car in the ListBox display the value of property RegistrationNumber
    listBox1.Displayember = nameof(Car.RegistrationNumber);
}
```

To Display the cars:

```
private ICollection<Car> DisplayedCars
{
    get => (ICollection<Car>)this.listBox1.DataSource;
    set => this.listBox1.DataSource = value;
}

public void DisplayCars()
{
    var carsToDisplay = this.FetchCars();
    this.DisplayedCars = carsToDisplay.ToList();
}
```

And Bingo: all the registration numbers of the cars are displayed.

This display is read-only. Changes that the operator makes: Add / Remove rows, change registration numbers, are not reflected.

This might not be a problem in your current application, but if later you decide to show your cars in a DataGridView, or if you want to use this method in a ListBox that the operator can edit, you might want automatic updating of changes that the operator makes. In that case you should use a BindingList:

```
private BindingList<Car> DisplayedCars
{
    get => (BindingList<Car>)this.listBox1.DataSource;
    set => this.listBox1.DataSource = value;
}
```

To get the selected Car:

```
private Car SelectedCar => (Car)this.listBox1.SelectedItem;
```

Or if you allow multiselect:

```
private IEnumerable<Car> SelectedCars = this.listBox1.SelectedItems.Cast<Car>();
```

### Back to your question

> I want to populate some textboxes when I select the registration number in the listbox.

So if the operator selects a Registration number in the list box, you want to display several values of Car properties of the selected Car.

Using visual Studio Designer, or in the constructor:

```
this.listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += OnCarSelected;

private void OnCarselected(object sender, ...)
{
    Car selectedCar = this.SelectedCar;
    this.DisplayCarProperties(selectedCar);
}

private void DisplayCarProperties(Car car)
{
    this.textBoxHireCost.Text = car.HireCost.ToString(...);
    this.textBoxYear.Text = car.ManufacturingYear.ToString();
    ...
}
```

### Conclusion

By separating your data from the way that you view your data, your code is much easier to read. The methods are usually one or two lines code. Methods are highly reusable and both the model and the view are easy to change. It is possible to unit test the model without the view.